# How to insert NULL value in cl-dbi

Tags: common-lisp, cl-dbi

I have the following table allowing for NULL values

```
CREATE TABLE test (
       test int, 
       test2 int);
```

A regular query allows inserting NULL values:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test (test, test2) VALUES (NULL, NULL)
```

However, using cl-dbi it does not work

```
(cl-dbi:execute
  (cl-dbi:prepare connection
                  "INSERT INTO test (test, test2)
                   VALUES (?,?)")
  nil
  nil)
```

results in

```
DB Error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "false" (Code: 22007)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the `:null` value as indicated [here](https://github.com/fukamachi/cl-dbi/issues/38).

```
(cl-dbi:execute
  (cl-dbi:prepare connection
                  "INSERT INTO test (test, test2)
                   VALUES (?,?)")
  :null
  :null)
```